# update_post_meta() updating nested array in Multidimensional array with empty sub-array

Tags: post-meta, array

How can i update/remove/empty a sub-array on user post submission in admin area?

here ist the [reference on how to update nested array](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/#div-comment-5411)  i am using but it is not working

```
if ( $post->post_type == 'ds_product' ) {
     
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['meta'] ) ) { 
        if ( !empty($_POST['meta']['ds_product_gallery']) ){
             
            $gallery_data = []; 

            for ($i = 0; $i < count( $_POST['meta']['ds_product_gallery']['picture'] ); $i++ )
            {
                if ( !empty($_POST['meta']['ds_product_gallery']['picture'][ $i ]))
                {
                    $gallery_data['picture'][ ]    = $_POST['meta']['ds_product_gallery']['picture'][ $i ];
                    $gallery_data['figcaption'][ ] = $_POST['meta']['ds_product_gallery']['figcaption'][ $i ];
                }
            }

            if ( !empty($gallery_data) ) {
                $_POST['meta']['ds_product_gallery'] = $gallery_data;
            } 
        
        }else{  
            // this section doesn't clear the array
            $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta', true );  
            $data['ds_product_gallery'][0][0] = [];
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'meta', $data[0] ); 
            
        } 
        foreach( $_POST['meta'] as $key => $value ){
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value );
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do it the same way as any other PHP application, this isn't a WordPress problem.

To remove an item from an array in PHP, use `unset( thing to remove )`.

E.g.

```php
$test = [ 'banana', 'cucumber', 'apple' ];
unset( $test[1] );
// cucumber is no longer in the test array, and the array now has 2 not 3 items
```

Comment: have a look at the else section that is exactly what i am doing but it doesn't work i even tried `$data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta', true );  
                $data['ds_product_gallery'] = [];
                update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'meta', $data ); ` without success

Comment: `$data['ds_product_gallery'][0][0] = [];` sets it to an empty array, if you want to remove the item from the array though then that's a general PHP problem not a WordPress problem, you can rephrase this question as "How do I remove an item from an array", use `unset()`.

Comment: ok mate, but how do you update the meta then? i tried `$data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta', true );  
                unset($data['ds_product_gallery']);
                update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'meta', $data ); ` but nothing

Comment: you update the meta by grabbing its value, changing that value, then updating it, you've already figured out that part

Comment: Here's the relevant doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php, as I said, this isn't a WordPress problem, it's a generic PHP problem. If your meta still has the values you tried to remove, it's because you did not remove them successfully. Either that or the code you're trying to debug is never run to begin with

Comment: Also `$_POST['meta']['ds_product_gallery']` is a weird thing to see, are you absolutely sure that is correct? And have you verified that the update meta call is actually happening? Not a "it should be" but an "I saw output that can only happen inside that `else` statement" or a pause on a debugger?

Comment: yes it is correct since i can update it delete it but not empty it meaning when i have 4items in it and just delete 3 it works fine but not if i delete all 4items. And that is where i am currently stuck

Comment: you mean you can remove items from the meta, but you cannot empty the entire thing? That was not obvious from your question ( I'm still not sure I have the right understanding). This isn't very clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134638/discussion-between-gildas-tambo-and-tom-j-nowell).